# Will this always work? And can it be improved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get ajax navigation working so here's what I tried:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html( $(data).find('#content').html() );
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is since everything is relatively linked none of my links or `img`s work. To make it even worse it tries to load all the `img`s even the ones I'm not using (automatic `img` preloading) and the relative path to my logo is incorrect for some pages.

If I change all the `src` and `href` occurences then run it through regex to to find and replace all bad paths then change the attrs back to `src` and `href` will it work?

Here's what I mean.

```
$('nav a').on('click', function() {
    var href = this.href 
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function(data) {
            var html = data.replace(/href/g, 'hrefhref')
                .replace(/src/g, 'srcsrc');

            $('#content').html(
                $(html).find('#content').html().replace(/hrefhref/g, 'href')
                    .replace(/srcsrc/g, 'src')
                    .replace(/href=\.\/'/g, "href='" + href)
                    .replace(/href=\.\/"/g, 'href="' + href)
                    .replace(/src=\.\/'/g, "src='" + href)
                    .replace(/src=\.\/"/g, 'src="' + href)
            );
        }
    });
});
```

My question is: Is there any way to make it work if paths dont start with a dot?
Of course it shouldn't change anything if the href or src attr is on another domain or already absolutely pathed

Also will this always work across all browsers, will having an attr `hrefhref` and `srcsrc` ever get stripped out when being parsed.

Comment: Sounds like you should be fixing this server side instead of client side. Why are you returning bad paths?

Comment: @mrtsherman:  I'm not, the paths are relative to the page that it should be on, not the page that's requesting it. eg, `me.com/` pointing to `img.gif` is referring to a different place than `me.com/about/` pointing to `img.gif`

Comment: @qwertymk Why not use absolute paths, then -- `/img.gif`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: because I'm developing it locally and the absolute paths I have on my computer aren't the same as on the server

Comment: Your approach is the wrong one. As Jonathan mentions, if you use a slash to prepend an image url it will automatically fill in the server url. So for example `http://localhost/img.gif` and `http://myserver.com/img.gif` will be automatically generated by `/img.gif`. Correct this server side not client side.

Comment: @mrtsherman: no, on my desktop, the file will be at `localhost/xampp/blah/img.gif` and on my server it's `me.com/img.gif`

Comment: As has already been suggested, *absolutely the best thing* to do here is to set up a virtual host, so that `http://localhost/xampp/blah/` becomes something like `http://blah.local/`. Then you can simply use `/img.gif`. The reason I'm adding this comment is that you added a bounty *after* the correct answer to your problem was already provided..

Comment: _"Is there any way to make it work if paths dont start with a dot?"_ - yes. _"will this always work across all browsers"_ - no

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `BASE` element in the set up.  That way, you can develop locally and you can put it on the server.  The only thing you'd have to change is your href in the `BASE` element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4

Or see the "dreaded and woeful" W3Schools explanation too: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need the paths to be absolute

Comment: That's the point of using that element.  You can use something like `<img src="images/smilie.jpg" />`, and if your base href is set to "http://localhost/dev/applied-cryogenics.com/" you'll have it resolve to "http://localhost/dev/applied-cryogenics.com/images/smilie.jpg", whereas if you have base href set to "http://applied-cryogenics.com", then the same `<img src="images/smilie.jpg" />` will resolve to "http://applied-cryogenics.com/images/smilie.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

You can use a virtual host to ensure that the absolute paths are the same between dev and local.

Comment: I'm developing in NetBeans, how would I do that?

Comment: @qwertymk are you running a local server like Apache?

Comment: This article will help you set up a Virtual host: http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

Comment: While your answer patches the problem, I'm looking for something a little more extensive, like if I wanted to make it into a jQuery plugin, I can't ask everyone to change their paths to be absolute. Also you didn't address if there can be any problems by having weird attrs like `srcsrc` and `hrefhref`

Comment: @qwertymk - at the risk of sounding mean - what you are trying to do is dumb. It is the exact opposite of how this should be handled. Of course you should ask people to change their paths, otherwise you have to rely on a hacky js fix that breaks your site for non-js users, is prone to failure and makes developing your code in a staging vs. production environment more difficult. The only benefit is that you get to be lazy and not fix your broken development platform.